# TableLayout placing

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

How to place TableLayout a grid of buttons 5 on 5 on the screen center?

```
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/Table5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:weightSum="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b11" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b12" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b13" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b14" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b15" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b21" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b22" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b23" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b24" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b25" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b31" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="b32" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b33" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b34" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b35" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b41" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b42" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b43" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b44" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b45" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b51" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b52" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b53" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b54" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b55" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use the above code in an android layout XML file to create your 5x5 button matrix using a TableLayout

Comment: happy that i helped you. would you mind it to mark as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:layout_gravity="center"` attribute to the `TableLayout`

(If that doesn't work, wrap the `TableLayout` with a `LinearLayout` or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/myGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />
```

and into grid_width, you can set a dimension (for hdpi, 480/5).
I don't know if this work for your situation. But try it

Comment: android:weightSum="5" don't meen: 5 lines and 5 columns. Is used like "percentage" when u can set the space for each item into linearLayout, for example.